# Why output of number of 'K' are more than the input characters?

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar, putchar

Isn't the input and output number of characters be the same?

```
int ch;

while(ch != '\n')
{
    ch = getchar();
    putchar('K');
}
```

Comment: Btw, `while(ch != '\n')` is undefined behaviour, since `ch` is uninitialized.

Comment: Also, getchar() returns an int, not a char.

Comment: @DeiDei and LeeDaniel Thanks for the answers.

Comment: But the problem is when I replace "putchar('K')" with "putchar(ch)" I'm satisfied with the output ie. same number of characters of input and output.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `ch` is not initialized. So the initial condition in the while loop has undefined behavior because the variable `ch` has indeterminate value.

Change the code snippet the following way

```
int ch;

while( ( ch = getchar() ) != '\n' && ch != EOF )
{
    putchar('K');
}
```

Pay attention to that `ch` is declared as having type `int`. Otherwise the code can not work if the type `char` is processed by the compiler as the type `unsigned char`.

As for your question

```
Why output of number of 'K' are more than the input characters?
```

then you at first are outputting the entered character and only after that checks it in the condition of the while statement. So outputted characters will be one greater than inputted characters if not to count the new line character as an inputted character.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm new here and your answer gives me even new more ideas eager to explore!! Your edited part makes me more simple to understand, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Others have mentioned that you're accessing an uninitialized variable, which causes undefined behavior. But even if you initialize it, the problem is that you're testing the variable `ch` *before* you read the character with `getchar()`. So the count will be off by 1.

Suppose you type `1\n`. The first iteration will compare the initial value of `ch` to `'\n'`. They won't match, so then it executes

```
ch = getchar();
putchar('K');
```

That's 1 K printed. Then it compares the new value of `ch` with `'\n'`. Since `ch == '1'`, they don't match, so it executes the loop body again. This reads the newline into `ch`, and prints a second `K`.

Then it repeats the loop. This time the test `ch != '\n'` fails, so the loop stops.

The number of `K` characters printed is the number of characters you typed *including* the newline.

One way to fix this is to call `getchar()` once *before* the loop.

```
int ch = getchar();
while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    putchar('K');
    ch = getchar();
}
```

Notice that you need to declare `ch` as an `int` variable so you can properly compare it with `EOF`.

Comment: Oh you sure knew that part where I got stuck even if I'm new here... Your answer is elegant and simple, I got 90% of it I got to study more. Thanks a lot!!